# INSERT INTO temporary table from sp_executsql

Tags: t-sql, temp-tables, sp-executesql, global-temp-tables

Generally, I am bulding dynamic SQL statement that is executing using sp_executsql like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @TempSQLStatement
```

I need to insert the return result row set in something (table variable or temporary table), but I am getting the following error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1746
Invalid object name '#TempTable'.
```

after executing this:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC sp_executesql @TempSQLStatement
```

From what I have read, I believe the issue is caused because I am not specifying the columns of the temporary table, but I am not able to do this because the return columns count varies.

I have read that I can use global temporary tables, but I have done this before and wonder is there an other way to do that.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. There is simply no way to create a #temptable from an EXEC output schema.

`INSERT ... EXEC` requires the table to exists (thus must know the schema *before* execution).

`SELECT ... INTO` does not support EXEC as a source.

Comment: So, I should use a global temporary table in the dynamic SQL statement to store the data and then to extract the data from it?

Comment: You should ask about a solution, but instead post the actual problem you're trying to solve. There are ways to achieve what you want, but is much better if you explain *why*. In general, try to avoid having to deal with unknown/untderemined result shapes, you'll keep hitting this problem and 'solutions' would simply shift the problem somewhere else, never solve it. SQL is a *not* a dynamic language.

Comment: Actually, knowing that I am not able to do this is quite enough. I will just change my logic to handle the situation. Thanks for helping me to clear this out.

Answer (score 3):

If you use INSERT INTO statement you have to create a table first.

Another way if you want to store  SQL statement result into the temp table you can use [SELECT ... INTO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) but in this case you should change `@TempSQLStatement` and add `INTO #TempTable` before `FROM` to get it.

For example if your @TempSQLStatement contains only one `FROM` keyword:

```
SET @TempSQLStatement=REPLACE(@TempSQLStatement,' FROM ',' INTO ##TempTable FROM ');
EXEC sp_executesql @TempSQLStatement; 

SELECT * from ##TempTable;
```

Comment: will break if the string  ` FROM ` appears more than once in @TempSQLStatement